# Second dialog is automatically destroyed when created from within a first dialog's OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

Basically, I have a login screen where users type their email and password to log in. After they have submitted their data, I check if they have confirmed their email address. If not, I display a dialog with a corresponding message. In that dialog I provide them with a neutral button to request a new confirmation email, if they haven't received one yet. If they clicked on that button, I wanna show another dialog with a message that the email has been successfully sent. The problem is that whenever I create and show the second dialog from within the first dialog's OnClickListener, the second dialog is instantiated, but then destroyed immediately. So my question is, why is this happening and how do I implement this kind of functionality so that whatever fragment is being shown will be retained across rotation?

NotVerifiedEmailDialog.java (first dialog):

```
public class NotVerifiedEmailDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "NotVerifiedEmailDialog";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.email_not_verified)
            .setMessage(R.string.email_not_verified_message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.request_new_email, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which)
                {
                    EmailSentDialog dialog = new EmailSentDialog();
                    dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), dialog.getMyTag());
                }
            })
            .create();
    }

    public String getMyTag()
    {
        return TAG;
    }
}
```

EmailSentDialog.java (second dialog):

```
public class EmailSentDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "EmailSentDialog";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(R.string.success)
                .setMessage(R.string.email_sent_message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .create();
    }

    public String getMyTag()
    {
        return TAG;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone encountered this problem, the solution is to replace `getChildFragmentManager()` with `getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager()`. The former gets a child fragment manager of the first dialog, which is gonna be destroyed, because of the button click (that's why the second dialog is destroyed instantly, because it is tied to the first dialog's child fragment manager), while the latter gets a child fragment manager of the parent fragment (in my case, LoginFragment) and, therefore, is not destroyed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following variable as instance variable. Your dialog object may get destroyed by the previous dialog.

```
EmailSentDialog dialog;
```

Comment: Tried it, but the same thing happens.